# PHP: Script showing parsing syntax error

Tags: php, singleton

I found an issue I can't seem to find a solution to. I am using a singleton class / method that return a single static PDO object. When I try to declare a static reference to the object (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BEpV.png), I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/o59sj.png . How would I go about fixing this?

Game Class:

```
<?php

    include_once('functions.php');
    include_once('database.php');

    $_codeRegex = '^([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,7})$';

    class Game
    {
        public $Id = "";
        public $Name = "";

        private static $connection = Database::Connect();

        public function __construct($id, $name)
        {
            $this->Id = $id;
            $this->Name = $name;
        }
    }

?>
```

My singleton Class:

```
<?php

    require_once('config.php');

    CONST CONNECTION_FORMAT = 'mysql:host=%1$s;dbname=%2$s;charset=utf8';

    class Database 
    {
        private static $cont = null;

        public function __construct() {
            exit('Initialize function is not excessible.');
        }

        public static function Connect()
        {
            if (self::$cont == null)
            {      
                try 
                {
                    $pdoConstuct = sprintf(CONNECTION_FORMAT, DB_SERVER, DB_NAME);
                    self::$cont = new PDO($pdoConstuct, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                    self::$cont->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) { return false; }
            }

            return self::$cont;
        }

        public static function Disconnect()
        {
            self::$cont = null;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: you can not use a function while declearing a property.

Comment: Didn't want to paste actual code?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VXM5dR2.png

Should I set it in the constructor?

Comment: Post code, not images of. You afraid we're going to steal your precious code?

Comment: No. Why would I be? It's not even that special.

Comment: Because, when someone needs to post an answer, he/she won't have to retype whatever needs to done in order to fix the problem.

Comment: Right. My apologies for my lack of doing that initially.

Comment: No problemo, *Welcome to Stack*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is not Java where you can define property values like this.

What you can do here is simply put property initialization into the `contructor`, like this:

```
    private static $connection;

    public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->Id = $id;
        $this->Name = $name;
        self::$connection = Database::Connect();
    }
```

When you define a class property in PHP you can not set its **default value** to instance of a class.

Comment: Thank you for a valid answer. I'm not yet used to Stackoverflow or PHP. I usually post my code via images on forums.

Comment: Also I recommend you to learn basic OOP things such as **Dependency Injection** and **Data Mappers**